# Creating a new column according to reference table

Tags: powerbi

​

I am relatively new to PowerBI and  I was wondering if someone would be able to help with something I am stuck on. I have the following table (ProductDate) with information in the format below:

| Product number | Date | Day of week |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5JR38 | 16 September 2022 | Friday |
| 5JR38 | 17 September 2022 | Saturday |
| 5JR38 | 18 September 2022 | Sunday |
| 7QP13 | 12 September 2022 | Monday |
| 7QP13 | 13 September 2022 | Tuesday |
| 7QP13 | 14 September 2022 | Wednesday |
| 7QP13 | 15 September 2022 | Thursday |
| 7QP13 | 16 September 2022 | Friday |
| 7QP13 | 17 September 2022 | Saturday |
| 7QP13 | 18 September 2022 | Sunday |

​

I also have another table (ProductStock) with the number of stock available for a specific day of the week range:

| Product number | Day ref | Stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5JR38 | FriO | 20 |
| 5JR38 | WEnd | 65 |
| 7QP13 | MFriO | 7 |
| 7QP13 | MidWeek | 13 |
| 7QP13 | WEnd | 18 |

​

The Day ref column in the table above refers to a range of dates which are stored in a separate table (DayReference) as follows:

| Day ref | Day of the week |
| --- | --- |
| FriO | Friday |
| MFriO | Monday |
| MFriO | Friday |
| WEnd | Saturday |
| WEnd | Sunday |
| MidWeek | Tuesday |
| MidWeek | Wednesday |
| MidWeek | Thursday |

​

The 'Day ref' column in the ProductStock table does not overlap (i.e.  for a 'Product Number' there is no 'Day ref' which would refer to a day of the week twice).

What I am trying to do is create a new column using DAX in the first table (ProductDate) with the 'Day ref' populated from the ProductStock tablewith their corresponding day of the week. The expected result should be something like this:

| Product number | Date | Day of week | Relevant Day ref |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5JR38 | 16 September 2022 | Friday | FriO |
| 5JR38 | 17 September 2022 | Saturday | WEnd |
| 5JR38 | 18 September 2022 | Sunday | WEnd |
| 7QP13 | 12 September 2022 | Monday | MFriO |
| 7QP13 | 13 September 2022 | Tuesday | MidWeek |
| 7QP13 | 14 September 2022 | Wednesday | MidWeek |
| 7QP13 | 15 September 2022 | Thursday | MidWeek |
| 7QP13 | 16 September 2022 | Friday | MFriO |
| 7QP13 | 17 September 2022 | Saturday | WEnd |
| 7QP13 | 18 September 2022 | Sunday | WEnd |

I don't really want to create a many-to-many relationship between those tables and would prefer if I add a new column as shown above. Any help or guidance will be much appreciated.

​

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in the **Advanced Query Editor**. Just open the **Advance Editor** for table **ProductDate** and try to incorporate this below code there-

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMvUKMrZQ0lEyNFMITi0oSc1NSi1SMDIwMgKKuRVlpiRWKsXqICkzx1QWnFhSWoSh0AKLwtI8mDLzwABDY5AyI0xlvvmYyowxlYWUphZjqDPBVBeempKHRaUpFhMzSoswFeIPGLgyQgEDV4gnYGIB", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Product number" = _t, Date = _t, #"Day of week" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Product number", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Day of week", type text}}),
    
    //--------------------------
    //New steps started from here
    //---------------------------
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type", {"Day of week"}, DayReference, {"Day of the week"}, "DayReference", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded DayReference" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "DayReference", {"Day ref"}, {"DayReference.Day ref"}),
    #"Merged Queries1" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded DayReference", {"Product number", "DayReference.Day ref"}, ProductStock, {"Product number", "Day ref"}, "ProductStock", JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Expanded ProductStock" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries1", "ProductStock", {"Day ref"}, {"ProductStock.Day ref"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded ProductStock",{"DayReference.Day ref"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"ProductStock.Day ref", "Relevant Day ref"}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Product number", Order.Ascending}, {"Date", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

Here is the output-

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately I don't think the code is working exactly as intended. The code you shared marks all Fridays as 'MFriO'. However, what I had in mind is that every Friday (or any other day of the week) is marked according to the matching 'Product Number' and 'Day ref' columns in the ProductStock table.

Comment: Thank you for your edit and modified code. That worked great and it was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Comment: You are most welcome @Fold_In_The_Cheese. Nice to see it helped :)